# python global variable not defined in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, global-variables

This code gives the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'LINES' referenced before assignment` but `LINES` is clearly initialized since if I comment out the line below the print statement it throws no errors and prints  `len(lines) = 0` as expected.  Am I not understanding something about python?? Whats going on here?

```
LINES = []

def foo():
  for prob in range(1,3):
    print "len(lines) = %d" % len(LINES)
    LINES = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
  foo()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *access* global variable from inside `foo`, but you can't rebind them unless the `global` keyword is used

So you can use `LINES.append(...)` or `LINES[:] = []` as they are merely modifying the list that LINES references.

When you try to assign to `LINES` using `LINES = []`, Python knows it needs to create an entry for LINES in the functions local variables. Since you are trying to use `len(LINES)` before assigning anything to the local variable, it causes an error

You can inspect `foo` like this

```
>>> foo.func_code.co_nlocals
2
>>> foo.func_code.co_varnames
('prob', 'LINES')
```

If you define `foo` again without the `LINES = []`, you'll see that Python no longer marks it as a local variable.

Answer (score 5):

[You need to use the `global` keyword:](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/global.html)

```
def foo():
  global LINES
  for prob in range(1,3):
    print "len(lines) = %d" % len(LINES)
    LINES = []
```

Otherwise, Python will think that `LINES` is local, and printing out the value before setting it to `[]` will be an issue

You can get the value of global variable `LINES` by printing it out, but when you have the statement

```
LINES = []
```

which tries to set `LINES` to a new list, Python interprets it as a local variable

Comment: I see. but why is it that it works when `LINES = []` is commented out or replaced with `LINES.append(prob)`?

Answer (score 1):

As Desired Login said,

> Since you assign to LINES in your example function, python knows not to use the global variable, but you attempt to access this variable before you define it.

This is not the end, you can fix this by using a global keyword, telling python that the `LINES` in the function is the same as the `LINES` outside of the function.

Try:

```
LINES = []

def foo():
  global lines
  for prob in range(1,3):
    print "len(lines) = %d" % len(LINES)
    LINES = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
  foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python will first look in the function scope for your variable, before it looks in the global (module level) scope. Since you assign to `LINES` in your example function, python knows not to use the global variable, but you attempt to access this variable before you define it. You should either initialise `LINES` before the print statement, or leave out the `LINES = []` statement.